# How to install older Android versions on a device

Tags: android, nexus-s

I would like to be able to test my Android app on different Android versions on an actual device, rather than on the emulator.  I have a Nexus S which currently has Android 2.3.6 installed.

My understanding is that I can boot into "recovery" mode on my phone and load an Android package from the SD card, but where can I find the official Android releases?  Are they distributed along with the SDK somewhere?

Comment: I finally found this link, which has a list of download links for the Nexus S:

[link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/archive/index.php/t-1063664.html)

Unfortunately these all seem to be for builds of Android 2.3, when I'm really interested in testing on older versions (2.2, 2.1, and earlier).

I'm really surprised that this information is not provided more officially by Google, and also that it is so difficult to find from other sources.  I guess people are testing older versions of Android on the emulator only (if at all).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you will have to root your device and then 'flash' another version of android onto it.

Here is a tutorial to get you started: http://nexusshacks.com/nexus-s-hacks/how-to-root-nexus-s-or-nexus-s-4g-new/

Comment: Just to clarify, this is a developer phone, so unless I'm mistaken, I don't need to root it to install another version.  Also, the main question I have is where to find the official Android releases.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I am speaking from personal experience here, I have a ZTE blade and in order to flash a new OS you must root my phone. However I have *heard* that developer phones are rooted, though I'm not sure. I think a simple Google search would do the trick here. Be warned however, that flashing a new OS will likely erase all of your current data, so be sure to back up first!

Answer (score 0):

The Nexus S was the first android 2.3 phone as far as I'm aware.  There won't be any official android releases earlier than that for it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe 2.2 and earlier are listed anywhere,
however, you can check [the factory images for nexus devices](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) and you might find an explanation why they do not list earlier versions